# How to click on a website's button using VBA and the button's details

Tags: html, excel, vba

I wrote a piece of code that logs into a website using my credentials. Now I want it to click on a button present on that page.

Here is an image of what the button HTML code looks like:

[image]

This is the piece of code I wrote to click on this button:

```
  With objIE
    .Navigate "https://www.ndexsystems.com/fengine/fullservice/en/kerrfinancialsalogin.go?fromLogoff=true" ' Main page

    .Visible = 1
    Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
   Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
            Set IeDoc = .document
            Set the_input_elements2 = IeDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each input_element2 In the_input_elements2
                If input_element2.href = "javascript:directToSearch()" Then
                    input_element2.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next input_element2

End With
```

This code is not working though. I cannot figure out what information to extract from the HTML code in order to click the button correctly.

I even tried `Set the_input_elements2 = IeDoc.getElementsByClassName("parent-item")`

Comment: what does _not working_ mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: @QHarr no error message. just nothing happening